# How do you create entity diagrams in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How do you create those entity/class diagrams in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To begin, open a project in Visual Studio and follow these steps:

- In the Solution Explorer window, right click the project and select “Add -> New Item”.
- From the Add New Item dialog box, highlight “Class Diagram” and give it a name.
- Press the Add button. The Class Diagram file will be added to your project and the designer will open.

To add an existing class to the diagram, simply drag and drop it from the Solution Explorer window onto the design surface. To create a new Class (or Struct, Enum, etc.), right click in the designer and expand the “Add ->” menu item. Select the appropriate type and follow the instructions.

Read more [here](http://www.developingfor.net/visual-studio/visual-studio-2008-class-diagram.html).

Answer (score 2):

Create a new project, right click on the solution and hit View Class Diagram.

Not quite sure you can create classes that way though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to *Class Diagrams,* follow Ekeko's instructions.

If you're referring to the *Entity Framework*, you'll need to download Visual Studio 2008 SP1, which includes the latest bits for the Entity Designer.  Once installed, you can create a new Entity Data Model in the visual designer by adding a New Item: "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".